# Mass insert using dynamic text boxes

Tags: php

is it possible to use dynamic text boxes to  to retrieve values and then insert those values into a database using pdo... wanting to do a mass insert

```
<?php 
for ($counter=1; $counter<=$number_box; $counter++)
{
?>

    <label>(x<?php echo $counter?>: <input name="x<?php echo $counter;?>" type="text" value=""/>,&nbsp </label>
    <label>(y<?php echo $counter?>: <input name="y<?php echo $counter;?>" type="text" value=""/>)</label><br /><br />
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: So make it an array like this `<label>(x<?php echo $counter?>: <input name="x[]" type="text" value=""/>,&nbsp </label>` Do you want like this?

Comment: if i do it that way is it possible to send those array values to a database using PDO